# <ask> How to Backup and Restore HDFS

Tags: hadoop, backup, hdfs, restore

Actually i have develop application which use Hdfs to store image.Now i want to migrate server and setup hadoop again in new server.How i can backup  my image file in HDFS (old sever) to HDFS in my new server ?

I've try to use **CopyToLocal** command to backup and **CopyFromLocal** to restore, but i've error, when application running, image which i've restore on hdfs can't show on my application.

How to solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Distcp is the command to use when performing data for large inter/intra-cluster copying. [Here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.2/distcp.html) is the documentation for the same.

CopyToLocal and CopyFromLocal should also work well for small amounts of data. Run the [HDFS CLI](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.19.2/hdfs_shell.html) and make sure that the files are there. Then it might be a problem with the application.

Comment: Hi Praveen, I've successfull backup and restore data between HDFS with command : /hadoop distcp hdfs://[source]:[port]/directoryA hdfs://[destination]:[port]/directoryA .When i try to running my app with new hadoop which i restore, my image show successfully. :).Thanks